# Angular NgbModal. How to make specific modal be topmost all other modals?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) library.

**What's from the box?**

When two modals are shown the backdrop of the top one doesn't cover the body of bottom one.

**What's the task?**

The task is to make one specific modal and it's backdrop be topmost all other modals.

The library itself [doesn't provide](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2016) the necessary API.

Is there any workaround to solve the problem?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao the OP apparently answered his own question, but Ramesh moved the answer to the question, and edited the answer to "This is does not an answer. It has moved to question." for a reason that I can't explain, and then you deleted the edited answer. Please undelete the original answer provided by the OP.

Comment: you can also answer your question again. Answering his own question is fine, and Ramesh shouldn't have edited your question and your answer. But you should edit your question to make it look like an actual question, with a question mark: "I'd like to have a modal on top of another modal in ng-bootstrap. I know this is not supported, nut is there any possible workaround?"

Answer (score 3):

Add `ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  templateUrl: './modal-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-content.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <-- this
})
```

Then you have two options:

Option 1 *class name selector*:

Add to css file:

```
.custom-ngb-modal-window {
 z-index: 999;
}

.custom-ngb-modal-backdrop {
 z-index: 999;
}
```

Then apply them in your options:

```
const options = { windowClass: 'custom-ngb-modal-window', backdropClass: 'custom-ngb-modal-backdrop' };
this.modalService.open(DialogComponent, options);
```

Option 2 *element selector*:

add to scss or css:

```
ngb-modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 999 !important;

}
ngb-modal-window{
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Comment: It works by using css `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

To make one modal topmost all others I used `NgbModalOptions.container`:

```
const options: NgbModalOptions = {
  ...
  container: '.session-modal-container'
};
```

It puts my modal into a special top-most container prepared in the root component.

HTML:

`<div class="session-modal-container"></div>`

CSS:

```
.session-modal-container .modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 1051;
}
.session-modal-container .session-dialog {
  z-index: 1052;
}
.session-modal-container .modal-dialog {
  margin: 30vh auto;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

In parent class, set css class name.

```js
const options: NgbModalOptions = {
  backdropClass: '.app-session-modal-backdrop',
  windowClass: '.app-session-modal-window'
};

this.modalService.open(DialogComponent, options)
```

In dialog Class, set component `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```js
@Component({
  styleUrls: [dialog.component.scss],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

And in dialog css class, use css class name defined parent class. And write z-index you desired. not to forget to add `!important`.

```css
ngb-modal-window.app-session-modal-window {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
ngb-modal-window.app-session-modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the style and given important. It works. Basically My problem was modal above i need to display the Mat autocomplete, this has `z-index:1000`  Tried a lot.

```
::ng-deep ngb-modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 999 !important;

}
::ng-deep ngb-modal-window{
  z-index: 999 !important;

}
```